# DevOps Promotion Failed, how to change or delete?

Tags: apex, callout, change-set, pipelines, devopscenter

Our team is using a DevOps Pipeline that starts from our individual sandbox, moves to an integrated sandbox, moves to a full sandbox, and then attempts to deploy to production.  In my sandbox, I updated ClassA to perform a callout.  Then I realized that an older batch ClassB was failing, because it was calling the ClassA.  I added a Mock to the batch ClassB_test file, tested it (it passed) and decided to move both changes through the pipeline.
I went through the integrated sandbox, the staging sandbox, using the Default test methods, until I got to Production.  Everything was passing just fine up to this point.

Once I tried to promote it to production, I received an error "Too many callouts."  I realized that the batch ClassB was not compatible with the updated ClassA.  However, now when I try to make changes to the Work Item, I get an error: "You can't make changes to a promoted work item. This work item has been promoted."

Honestly, we've realized this outdated ClassB could just be deleted, but now I don't seem to be able to fix the pipeline.

Any suggestions for how I can change or delete this change-set from the Pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delete a Work Item that has been promoted, you must go through the process of deleting the related Change Submission and related Remote Change files first.  These can be queried through the Developer Console using SOQL.

Delete the sf_devops__Remote_Change__c file that relates to ClassB, then delete the sf_devops__Change_Submission__c related to ClassB, then you can delete the sf_devops__Work_Item__c that contains ClassB.

Comment: Although a long route, but it certainly does help. Thanks for the deeper insights!